# Why does the Rust compiler generate huge executables?

Tags: rust

Compiling a simple hello world application like this:

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, World!");
}
```

Generates a relatively huge 822 KB executable using the default compiler options (`rustc hello.rs`).

Why does this happen and what is the best way to reduce the size of the executable?

Comment: AFAIK, much or all of the standard library is linked into the binary statically by default. Try optimization `-O` and/or `strip`. For kicks and giggles you may also link to libstd etc dynamically (not sure how, though).

Comment: `-Z lto` (link-time optimisations) shrinks things plenty too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. The standard library is linked statically by default. You can change that by passing the `-C prefer-dynamic` option to the compiler.
2. Rust is still a very young language with an incompletely optimized compiler. There is still a lot of room left for improvements in compilation speed, code speed and size, wording of error messages and so on.

Answer (score 0):

`rustc -C opt-level=2 hello.rs` gives a 4kb binary

Comment: This is not universally true. Using Rust 1.19.0 on macOS, this command produces a ~400K executable.